# Suggestions solutions for high current bed of nails style testing

Tags: high-current

I'm trying to create a tester board that will hold some power path components (DC input caps, IGBTs, current sensors) that are normally on the Unit Under Test (UUT).

I'd like to connect these components to the UUT through some spring-loaded probes. Are spring-loaded pins even a good way to do this? Should I be looking into alternate methods? Additionally, are high-current, PCB mount, spring loaded probes a common component or should I expect to not find very many?

This probe is an example of what I'd like to place on the baord [SHE-5-B-18.7-G](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Smiths-Interconnect-IDI/SHE-5-B-187-G?qs=Du1Eq8qdoupKOhs2Wv5BZA%3D%3D). Unfortunately it's not high enough current.

Comment: My go-to source for all things pogo pins is [Mill-Max](https://www.mill-max.com/new_products/detail/103).

Comment: Thanks! I'll check there!